# "Other" textbox in Refiner does not work

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, 2016, refiner

I have a refiner that maps on a taxonomy column. Teh refiner show the taxonomy items and I can "refine" them perfectly. Now I saw the input field below the taxonomy refiner

[image]

When I enter the same value like "Systembetreuung" it does not show any results. I go a way further and want to know why it does not filter correctly. It figured out that the token is different.

When it filters by the taxonomy value itself it create a filter token like "string(L0#|guid|Systembetreuung)".

```
http://win-ief18dunkfg/webtest/Seiten/56654654.aspx#Default={"k":"","r":[{"n":"owstaxIdesource","t":["string(\"L0|#087faa432-0001-0008-0000-e04330b12acd|Systembetreuung\")"],"o":"OR","k":false,"m":{"string(\"L0|#087faa432-0001-0008-0000-e04330b12acd|Systembetreuung\")":"Systembetreuung"}}]}
```

When it filters by the input field it creates a token like "equals("Systembetreuung")".

Example:

```
http://win-ief18dunkfg/webtest/Seiten/56654654.aspx#Default={"k":"","r":[{"n":"owstaxIdesource","t":["equals(\"Systembetreuung\")"],"o":"OR","k":false,"m":{"equals(\"Systembetreuung\")":"Systembetreuung"}}]}
```

I changed the URI for a test, so that it will replace the "equals" to "string", then it show mir the correct filtering.

So how I can archive that it use the correct token. Is there any setting that can do this?